# write a finite rank operator as sum of a nilpotent and diagonal operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, compact-operators

[image]

In the highlighted part, I don't see why we can write a finite rank operator as sum of a nilpotent and diagonal operators.

I know that if the space is of finite dimension, then we can write any operator as a upper triangular matrix. But here, the space could be infinite dimensional...

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The operator $B_n$ is finite-rank. So, as an operator $(\ker B_n)^\perp\to\operatorname{Ran}B_n$, it is an invertible operator between finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces of the same dimension. Which allows you to see $B_n$ as an $m\times m$ matrix, where $m=\dim\operatorname{Ran} B_n$.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Why can we write $B_n$ as the sum of $C_n $ and $D_n$? Is it because $A$ is quasi-nilpotent (my guess) ?

Comment: No, $A$ has nothing to do with it. It's the Jordan form: any square matrix is the sum of a nilpotent and a diagonal that has the eigenvalues. Or you can use Schur if you prefer it to Jordan.